# Macro to identify sections between borders

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of a macro that delineates my data visually with a bottom border:

```
'   Add line between each item
Sheets("Audit").Select
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
  If rng <> rng.Offset(1, 0) Then
    Range("A" & rng.Row & ":O" & rng.Row).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
  End If
Next rng
```

This separates transactions relating to each item into nice little sections. The problem is that, in order to catch everything I need, there is a lot of extraneous data and most sections are not relevant.  I have the relevant transactions bolded, but I need to see everything in the same "box" as the bolded transactions, so I can't simply use autofilter.

What I'm trying to get some direction on is somehow filtering out any section between borders that does not contain a bolded line (or only filtering in the sections that do contain a bolded line).  Also, the bolded lines are the only lines that have the word "remove" or "override" in column H, if it's easier to do it that way.  I'm at a loss on how to solve this even logically, much less with a macro.

Any ideas?

Edit:  I've added a helper column in which each row with a bottom border has "Line" in the M column, each bolded Remove transaction has a "Remove" in that column, and most cells in the column are blank.  The task now is to develop a macro to delete all rows between the "Lines" that do no contain a "Remove" between them.  So in the following example, I would want to delete rows 2-4, keep 5-9, and delete 10-11 (First row in each range is +1 due to the line drawn as a bottom border).

```
1 Line
2 
3 
4 Line
5
6 Remove
7
8
9 Line
10
11 Line
```

Comment: My guess is that a helper with a formula showing which lines to include in filter and not would help. You could filter based on results of this column. Since there's no sample data, it's hard to provide any more detail.

Comment: Let's say I made a helper column in which every underlined row had a "L" value in that column, and every bolded row had a "B" in that column.  Could I make a macro to delete any section where there is not a B between 2 Ls?

Comment: *Could I make a macro to delete any section where there is not a B between 2 Ls?* - Yes!

Comment: Any guidance or solutions to similar problems that I can adapt?  I'm currently playing around with Find to record the row numbers for each, but it feels clunky.