# Macro to identify and delete sections

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of a macro that delineates my data visually with a bottom border that separates transactions relating to each item into nice little sections. The problem is that, in order to catch everything I need, there is a lot of extraneous data and most sections are not relevant. I have the relevant transactions bolded, but I need to see everything in the same "box" as the bolded transactions, so I can't simply use autofilter.  Also all relevant transactions are "removes."

I've added a helper column in which each row with a bottom border has "Line" in the M column, each bolded Remove transaction has a "Remove" in that column, and most cells in the column are blank. The task now is to develop a macro to delete all rows between the "Lines" that do no contain a "Remove" between them. So in the following example, I would want to delete rows 2-4, keep 5-9, and delete 10-11 (First row in each range is +1 due to the line drawn as a bottom border).

```
1 Header Row
2  
3 
4 Line
5
6 Remove
7
8 Remove
9 Line
10
11 Line
12 Line
13
14
15 Remove
16 Remove
17
18 Remove
19 
20 Line
```

This is my current attempt:

```
'   Delete empty sections
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim LastWasLine As String
Dim LastLine As Long

LastWasLine = "True"
LastLine = 1
LastRow = Sheets("Audit").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rng3 In Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
    If rng3 = "Remove" Then
        LastWasLine = "False"
    ElseIf rng3 = "Line" Then
        If LastWasLine = "True" Then
            Range("M" & LastLine + 1 & ":M" & rng3.Row).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            LastLine = rng3.Row
            LastWasLine = "True"
        End If
    End If
Next rng3
```

It seems to behave properly until row 3583, and by properly I just means it deletes everything.  I can't really discern a pattern of what it does then, just keeps large chunks and then deletes one very large chunk, when it should be keeping and deleting many more smaller sections.  Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Original question here: [Macro to identify sections between borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632475/macro-to-identify-sections-between-borders)

Edit: got it working!  This is what I ended up with.  I need to continue testing and I'm sure it could be cleaned up a bit, but so far, so good.  Thanks Bruce!

```
'   Delete sections with no removals
Dim LastWasLine As String
Dim LastLine As Long
Dim i As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Audit").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
LastWasLine = "True"
LastLine = LastRow
Sheets("Audit").Range("M1").FormulaR1C1 = "Line"

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    With Sheets("Audit").Cells(i, "M")
        If .Value = "Remove" Then
            LastWasLine = "False"
        ElseIf .Value = "Line" Then
            If LastWasLine = "True" Then
                Sheets("Audit").Range("M" & i + 1 & ":M" & LastLine).EntireRow.Delete
                LastWasLine = "True"
                LastLine = i
            Else
                LastLine = i
                LastWasLine = "True"
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next i

'   Delete helper column
Sheets("Audit").Range("M:M").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: It's probably being weird because you're deleting a row, while going *down* that column.  Instead, "reverse" your logic.  Step through the macro, and/or put a break at the `...EntireRow.Delete` line, then step through after it deletes a row, I'm willing to bet that it will then skip some cells you intended to keep/remove...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, it was likely due to the way you were iterating down the column, removing columns, and continuing on without attributing for the now removed lines. ...any ways, how does this work?

```
Sub t()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim nextCellUp As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
LastRow = Sheets("Audit").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ' Note you're using Column C here...

For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    With Sheets("Audit").Cells(i, "M")
        If .Value = "Line" Then
            Set nextCellUp = .End(xlUp)
            If nextCellUp = "Line" Then
               'Sheets("Audit").Range(nextCellUp.Row + 1 & ":" & i).EntireRow.Select
                Sheets("Audit").Range(nextCellUp.Row + 1 & ":" & i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried to "tighten" it up a little. You could have also, instead of a string, just done `Dim wasLastLine as Boolean` and then a little more quickly check `if wasLastLine Then`, for times when the last line was "line" ...any ways, let me know if I understood it correctly!  I think I'm overlooking a scenario but it worked correctly with the sample data you gave above.

Comment: It takes forever and I don't quite understand how it works, but yes, it works great.  Thank you!  Given that my sheet is many 10s of thousands of rows, is it possible to tweak this by filtering only the cells with Line or Remove, then running your macro on that, but still deleting the filtered out rows in between?

Comment: On second glance, it looks like it deleted ~50 of the 200 sections I needed it to keep...

Comment: @Justin - Instead of posting a file online, can you perhaps expand the sample data you provided above? What's the circumstance where it deletes sections you intend to keep? Also I edited the code to hopefully speed it up a little.

Comment: Of course; the example is updated.  I can't really determine a pattern to what is missing, but I did a countif on the column and pre-macro there are 203 removes and post-macro there are 145.

Comment: See last edit.  I think I got it working.  Thanks for your help and feel free to critique if you see any opportunities to tighten up!